# Reuse transformation and other tasks in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I'm trying to build a large package with different source providers. A lot of processes have common tasks like lookups and data conversions, till now the only way I found to reuse is to just copy/paste, but if I suddenly decide to change something I have to change across all data flow tasks.

In general I want to connect several sources to the same lookup or transformation task.

I have a feeling that I'm missing something, thanks.

Comment: Why not create smaller packages to isolate the functionality that you want to reuse and call them from your large package passing the appropriate parameters? If something changes in the future you will only have to modify it once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, basically you need to store in variable (object type) your connection strings, then in for each loop take one connection and map to other string variable and map to your dataflow trough variables... So in the end you get same package but with different connections (database name and etc..) 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14341/Using-the-Foreach-ADO-Enumerator-in-SSIS

Comment: I don't think you can use variables much with Transformation Tasks as long as loops are not available inside Data Flow, but the article was useful tough, thanks.

Comment: Sorry which SSIS element you calling 'Transformation Task' ? Yes, 'For each loop' can't be placed in Dataflow, but you can place dataflow in 'for each loop' element ... I don't see in your question SSIS elements in which you wanna change connection strings? `I want to connect several sources to the same lookup or transformation task.` by this link you can do this, just if lookup element is same give him static connection string not variable and for 'Data source' element give variable connection string...